# React Native Live Reload

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, react-native

I'm using React Native on Windows 10 with the Android Studio Emulator, and I'm unable to get live reload working. Along with not being able to bring up the Dev menu with F2 (resorted to `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU` for that), but even when enabling it in there, it's still not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I reinstalled Node JS, which came with a later version of NPM than what I already had (3+). After re creating the project and running the packager, it's working!